# Dealing with multiple completion handlers

Tags: swift, concurrency, completionhandler, dispatch-queue

I'm trying to coordinate several completion handlers for each element in an array.

The code is essentially this:

```
var results = [String:Int]()

func requestData(for identifiers: [String])
{
    identifiers.forEach
    {   identifier in

        service.request(identifier, completion: { (result) in
            result[identifier] = result
        })
    }

    // Execute after all the completion handlers finish
    print(result)
}
```

So each element in the Array is sent through a service with a completion handler, and all the results are stored in an array. Once all of these handlers complete, I wish to execute some code.

I attempted to do this with `DispatchQueue`

```
var results = [String:Int]()

func requestData(for identifiers: [String])
{
    let queue = DispatchQueue.init(label: "queue")

    identifiers.forEach
    {   identifier in

        service.request(identifier, completion: { (result) in
            queue.sync
            {
                result[identifier] = result
            }
        })
    }

    // Execute after all the completion handlers finish
    queue.sync
    {
        print(result)
    }
}
```

but the print call is still being executed first, with an empty `Dictionary`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If I understand what are you are trying to do correctly, you probably want to use a `DispatchGroup`

Here is an example:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

var letters = ["a", "b", "c"]

for letter in letters {
    group.enter()
    Server.doSomething(completion: { [weak self] (result) in
        print("Letter is: \(letter)")
        group.leave()
    })
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("- done")
}
```

This will print something like:

```
b
c
a
// ^ in some order
- done
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once.  Can't believe how hard it was to track down this super useful piece of built-in functionality!

Answer (score 0):

First, take note that your `service.request(...)` is processed in asynchronous mode. Another problem is you want to finish all the service request in that loop.

My suggestion is create the function with completion handler and add a counter on each loop done. Your function will be similarly as below.

```
var results = [String:Int]()

func requestData(for identifiers: [String], callback:@escaping (Bool) -> Void)
{
    var counter = 0
    var maxItem = identifiers.count

    identifiers.forEach
    {   identifier in

        service.request(identifier, completion: { (result) in
            result[identifier] = result
            counter += 1
            if counter == maxItem {
                callback(true) // update completion handler to say all loops request are done
            }
            // if not, continue the other request
        })
    }
}
```

This is how another part of your code will call the function and wait for callback

```
requestData(for identifiers:yourArrays) { (complete) in

    if complete {
        print(results)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to manage if errors happened.